# Adding a column based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Reaching the end of some analysis, i have a single data frame (df_delta in the example) containing id, group, baseline, origination, subsequent_events, and delta_month.

My approach: merge, join or concatenate with subsequent events (df_a_b) then sum (concat shown in the snippet) based on id.

```
import pandas as pd
data_a = {
'id': [3, 2, 1, 0]
,'group':['test','test','control','control']
,'original_event_date': ['2018-01-02', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-20', '2018-01-01']
,'baseline':['100', '20', '1000', '5']
}
df_a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_a)

data_b = {
'id': [3,3,3,3, 1, 0,0]
,'subsequent_event_date': ['2018-02-02','2018-03-02','2018-04-02', '2018-01-15','2018-03-13', '2018-03-20', '2018-04-01']
,'subsequent_events':['3','5','7','2','20', '10', '5']
}
df_b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_b)

#assign original event month to each record [id]
df_a['origination'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['original_event_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

#sum subsequent events by record [id]                
df_sum_b = df_b.groupby(by=("id"))["subsequent_events"].sum()

#join the two to get delta_month
df_a_b = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], axis=1, sort=False) 

df_delta = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,how='left',on='id')
df_delta['delta_month'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_delta['subsequent_event_date']).dt.year - pd.to_datetime(df_delta['original_event_date']).dt.year) * 12 \
                    + (pd.to_datetime(df_delta['subsequent_event_date']).dt.month - pd.to_datetime(df_delta['original_event_date']).dt.month)

df_delta = df_delta.drop(columns=['original_event_date','subsequent_event_date']).fillna(0)
```

An ideal output would include: test/control, yyyy-mm of original event, delta_month as groups and a percentage of baseline sum for each delta_month.

Join, merge and concat don't seem to have this functionality. If each original event is associated with a subsequent event, the original event values where no subsequent events took place are lost and if both subsequent events and original events are summed in the same action there will be a multiple of the original event corresponding to the delta_month

Does anyone have any better suggestions on how to approach this differently?

Comment: Could you clearly state what's the input (I suspect that `df_a` and `df_b`, but this contradicts your description when you mention that you have `delta_month` in your first input dataframe) and provide an example of the desired output? Just provide `expected_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ ... })` with data filled by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would add as much to the ungrouped frames as possible (personal preference), so using `transform` is nice.

> the original event values where no subsequent events took place are lost

That can be resolved by `fillna`.  Since it looks like you want to sum `subsequent_events` numerically, we might as well cast as integers (or floats or ...) from the start.

```
df_delta['subsequent_events'] = df_delta['subsequent_events'].fillna('0').astype(int)
df_delta['sum_events_in_month'] = df_delta.groupby(['group','origination','delta_month'])['subsequent_events'].transform('sum').fillna(0)
df_delta['delta_month'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_sum_b = df_delta.groupby(['group','origination','delta_month'])[['baseline', 'sum_events_in_month']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())

df_sum_b['pct'] = df_sum_b['sum_events_in_month']/df_sum_b['baseline']
```

(Edit: the suggested edit did point out a flaw, though I don't think the solution worked; instead of `.astype(int).fillna(0)`, which breaks since missing values can't be integer-cast, I've swapped the order to `.fillna('0').astype(int)`.  Per the comment, I've added some more `fillna`s that seem to do the trick.)

Comment: thanks for your answer Ben - after looking through this method, the same problem persists. to replicate the error, use the snippet from the original question, replace after the creation of df_delta and print df_sum_b. test origination from 2018-02 (id 2) is missing.